# Aseprite - How do I create a glow effect?

Tags: pixel-art, sprite

**NOTE:** I copied this from the default Stack Exchange website. Additionally the picture attached is not my own.

This question is based on the software known as **Aseprite**, a sprite and pixel art creation software. This question isn't actually about how to operate this software but more-so a way of executing a desired effect.

So, I am creating a sprite and I wish to create a glow effect on a flame. I tried using the blur tool but I feel it does not give off the look of a glowing flame. What method(s) should I use to create a glow effect?

[image]

Comment: There are SOOOO many types of glow, bloom and haze that it's best if you find an example you think represents what you're trying to achieve. I think.

Comment: "I copied this from the default Stack Exchange website" huh? StackExchange.com itself doesn't have any questions. Do you mean you originally posted this on another SE site?

Comment: I believe it was the one which was primarily for programming and code. I felt it was in the wrong location so I moved it here instead. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @Confused I have the idea of what kind of glow I'd like to achieve but I am unsure of Aseprite has a tool specifically for making a glow.

Comment: Great. But the idea is only in your head. So for someone knowledgeable in AseSprite to answer your question you're going to need transfer that mental image to a more transparent and communicable medium. Like a digital image, here. Or master telepathy  ;)

Comment: @Confused I'm afraid that doesn't help, sorry.

Comment: If nobody can see the type of glow you want, then nobody can tell you it can be done, or how it can be done. In other words, to help readers help you, you need to help them with an image of the kind of glow you like.

Comment: @Confused Oh I think I understand what you're getting at. I would like to replicate a light akin to the one in the picture linked, using Aseprite's tools: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-pHeww1hN4zg/UtK9SkabG3I/AAAAAAAAB-Y/SonzCJsUUSo/s1600/cave_7.jpg The problem is I am uncertain how to create that kind of affect via Aseprite.

Comment: It could be that it isn't something that the application can do. This isn't exactly something that you'd see in traditional pixel art. You could use another application just for the glow. Like Photoshop or Gimp.

Comment: @Joonas Ah I suppose you're right about that, but I'm positive I've seen it been done before. I'd gladly use GIMP but unfortunately I cannot export my project as a PSD. :(

Comment: Well psd is not gimp's native format. Not that it matters. Any typical picture format should do, like jpg or one. The only concern might be editability and layers. If asperite  doesn't support a file format that supports layers, there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: And I'm sure you have seen it before, but that doesn't mean it was done in a pixel art application. Maybe more modern pixel art application, if there are any, could possibly have tools for that, but it still wouldn't surprise me if all of those glowy lights and soft gradients in pixel art were done using some sort of photo editing application and that there isn't a single pixel art application that can do it, unless you painstakingly do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have a partially transparent blurred circle in the top layer with blending mode Screen. Other blending modes can also be used, but Screen probably does most easily what's wanted:

[image]

Drawing the blurred circle so that the opacity decreases with the wanted rate to outwards from the center isn't one click thing, but you can make gradients in Aseprite. In my example there's a radial gradient from yellow to black. In blending mode Screen yellow and other light colors brighten, black doesn't affect.

Reduced layer opacity makes the effect more subtle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use circle filled tool and use a opacity level followed by smaller sequential overlapping opacity circles to create desired glow effect.